# AWS Cognito federated external user not found using adminListGroupsForUser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I configured my keycloak as a federated identity provider and I can see the new cognito user being created when I sign in through keycloak. The user email is set to verified in keycloak and correctly mapped in cognito as verified and shows up in the cognito users list as verified.

The issue is when I use nodejs adminListGroupsForUser() and provide the user id and the pool ID I get `UserNotFoundException: User does not exist.`

I tried the same with an user that is not externally provided and it works fine.
Is there an API limitation when it comes to external provided users?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Federated users have usernames derived from the IdP name and the userid/sub value provided by the IdP. e.g. `MyOIDCIdP_[sub]`

Source:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-specifying-attribute-mapping.html

Comment: Thank you, that solved part of the issue. Do you know how I could get the user details including the user name when inside a lambda function triggered by aws api gateway? I only have access to the user ID inside the req.apiGateway.event input json.